# Getting to where one can edit their profile is very unintuitive

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

So, on every other site where one has a profile, and said site displays a user's username or picture in the upper left, all one has to do in order to edit one's profile is to click said picture or username and choose "Profile" or "Edit Profile." However, on Stack Exchange, one must first go to the Meta "site" and THEN click on one's picture. Don't you guys have a "site" devoted to user interface design? Can't they tell you that this is stupid? Can't they tell you that if one must google how to do something so simple, and then the answers must include a link to get to where one can actually edit one's profile, then YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG?

Comment: When you say "every other site" do you mean "every other site on the Stack Exchange Network" and you're talking about changing your profile on stackexchange.com? Can you give a link to what you're talking about? An image?

Comment: I mean every other web site on the internet. The use of the term "site" within Stack Exchange is a misnomer. They are really all different parts or "forums" within the same overall "site."

Comment: No, they're not forums. They're Q&A sites. We're very specific that calling the SE sites "forums" is not accurate... "Forum" denotes discussion and conversation. Nothing about SE allows that except, to some degree, the meta sites.

Comment: OK, so "forum" is not appropriate because you don't want discussions. However, the main point still stands, they are sub-"sites" under one overall website. It is not unreasonable to expect to be able to edit one's profile directly from the TOP of that hierarchy.

Comment: @GrantRobertson But they *are* separate sites.  They are entirely separate from each other.  SE.com *isn't* "the top of that one site".  It's a *different site*.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com is not Q&A site, it's a portal. It has no real profile of its own, and it's not the "top" site, it just shows the collection of your sites. That is the source of confusion and will be addressed at some point in the future.

Comment: So, I see I am being downvoted like crazy, just for pointing out what would be painfully obvious to anyone who is not already a fan of the site. I am not wrong. The way one has to get to a point where one can edit one's main profile is not obvious or intuitive. But I see I am butting up against the same fan-boi brick wall as all over the rest of the internet. Speak the simple truth that someone doesn't want to hear and they will downvote you. It's actually a pretty sad commentary.

Comment: Questions here work better when they are openly looking for information rather than being rants. If you want help without downvotes, be more neutral in your question rather than accusing and being angry, ask for help finding what you're looking for. If you think it's confusing, show what's confusing and how you think it can be improved **without** being rude about it.

Comment: The downvotes here are because people disagree with your statement that it's hard to find the edit profile option. It's not. And in case one having hard time finding it, the answer can be found easily here with quick search, or just asking.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard - My point is that something as utterly basic and common as that should NEVER require searching or asking. When something that basic and common is unintuitive TO AN UNINITIATED USER then it is not intuitive. And stating that fact is also not wrong. Just because you are used to the weird way in which something works, does not mean that it is a reasonable way to do it. Therefore, it is obvious that the downvotes are merely because I am saying something you don't want to hear. I've wasted too much time on this already.

Comment: We all admit that any site can work on improving their new user experience but by coming here and posting a rant rather than asking a question, you're really not encouraging us to help you as a new user. Being new and unknowledgable about how the system works is perfectly OK but ranting about the structure without being open to learning how it works is not.

Comment: @Catija - If people like me don't rant then people like you don't pay attention. I already googled the question and found the answer. If you think that having thousands of people per day needing to google an answer to such a simple thing is an appropriate way to handle design issues then I feel bad for all your users. I ranted, specifically to get your attention and to draw attention to the very poor design problem. If I just humbly asked, all you would do is tell me the convoluted way I should "fix my problem" and then consider yourself to have been helpful and successful. ....

Comment: @Catija - ... And you would never have thought for an instant that the real "problem" was really in the design itself.

Comment: I promise you, opening an honest request for attention is *much more effective* than ranting is. No one said you had to google an answer to this, though. If your question had been posted here as "How can I change my profile without having to go to Meta" - without the rant, you would have had it explained to you (as it was). If you'd wanted to suggest a change, you can do that without screaming at us about how awful the design is. You can make assumptions about how this site works all you want, but I assure you, no one respects people who rant enough to consider what they want changed.

Comment: @Servy - You may believe that SE is not at the top of the SE hierarchy, but for all intents and purposes, it is. For anyone looking at this system of "sites" it looks exactly as if SE is the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: I hadn't seen SE until quite a while after I had used some of the other sites. You maybe just got to that one first. And to be honest, I would never want to edit all of mine at once, as I tailor them - because each site is very different.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to go to meta to edit your profile.

All you have to do is be on any site, click on your profile picture, and then click on "Edit Profile & Settings", and you can edit your profile.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. But that seems weird too. Do I have to edit my profile on every different "site"? That would be a total pain in the rear.

Comment: @GrantRobertson there's very clearly a tick box for "change all sites"...

Comment: @GrantRobertson Try editing it and see what happens.

Comment: @Catija Nope, no tick boxes.  There's two buttons that you can use to save your profile.  Not sure when that changed, but once upon a time it was a tick box.

Comment: Let me go back and look. It still seams weird. When I am on the main Stack Exchange website and try to change my profile, the only option I get is to copy the profile from some other "site." It just all seems back-asswards to me. But whatever. I ain't got all day to sort out why the biggest tech website in the world has a stupid user interface for changing one's profile.

Comment: Yes, there is a button at the bottom of the screen to "Save and copy changes to all public communities." I still contend that that is unintuitive and not really obvious, when first looking for how to edit one's main profile. I mean, think about it. The instructions for editing the main profile are: Go to some sub-site. Edit profile there. Scroll to bottom of screen and choose the utterly unexpected "Save and copy changes to all public communities" button. 

Remember, just because something works, and YOU know how to do it, does not mean it is intuitive or correct.

Comment: @GrantRobertson Did you try clicking on your profile picture, and then clicking on "edit profile".  Considering it's literally exactly what you said you were expecting to see, and what every other site out there does, and it's exactly what SE does, your complains make little sense.

Comment: When on the main Stack Exchange home page (not within any specific sub-"site") clicking on the picture only goes to a page to view my profile. At the bottom right of my bio, there is a tiny link to "Update profile info" but that only allows me to copy profile information from one of the sub-"sites." You can imagine my confusion, especially as someone who does not come to Stack Exchange often.

Comment: I literally had to google how to edit my profile.

Comment: Remember, just because something works, and YOU don’t know how to do it, does not mean it is unintuitive or incorrect.